# background image for div

Tags: html, css, division

I have a html file with div for which I want to add an background using CSS so that I can change it using jQuery or JavaScript.

In HTML file:

```
<html>
      <head>
           <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      </head>

     <body>
           <div id="mydiv">
           </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

In `style.css` I have:

```css
#mydiv {
    background-image: url("images/bg.png");
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

> it is showing a blank page what is an error in this simple code

Comment: And the question is what, exactly?

Comment: you need help relating to javascript code?

Comment: you need to set width and height to your div.

Comment: Your image url is wrong? The div has no width or height? The image doesn't exist? The path to your CSS file is wrong? Have you checked any of these things?

Comment: Either your image path is wrong or it is because you haven't set a width or height: `background-size:100px 100px;width:100px;height:100px;`

Comment: does your image even exists?

Comment: Is your relative image path correct? Does your image exist? Are you setting width and height in percentage? If so, if you body and html height set? There are too many querstions. This is so basic that you will have to tell us more.

Comment: and check you images folder path maybe? can it be like url('../images/bg.png') because it's in another folder?

Comment: let's inspect element with crome or with ff, and move your mouse over your image of your css property. it should show your image, or say can not load url.

Comment: no all things are correct i tried same with background color and using same path in <img> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was fine, but you needed a **defined** width and height for your `<div>`.  Also, I replaced your image so you could see that **it does** work.

### http://jsfiddle.net/d4pyokh9/1/

Comment: background-size: contain
after adding this in css it started showing same images in 10 rows
image size is 76px   *    5000px

Comment: You can use `background-repeat: no-repeat;` to fix that.  http://jsfiddle.net/d4pyokh9/1/

Comment: You also may need to change your `<div>`'s size based on your image's size.

Answer (score 0):

Your  div doesn't have any content, therefore it's not going to show anything. If you want a background on the entire page then change the css to:

```
body {
    background-image: url("images/bg.png");
}
```

Otherwise change the css to:

```
#mydiv {
    background-image: url("images/bg.png");
    min-height: /* some size here */;
    min-width: /* some other size here*/;
}
```

[You also may want to look into background parameters in regards to repeat-x and repeat-y](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background).

Answer (score 0):

You should define width and height of div and also background-size for the image,like(background-size:100% 100%;)

Answer (score -2):

mydiv has no height/width so the background image is too small to see.

Try:

```
#mydiv {
    background-image: url("images/bg.png");
    height: 1000px;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

And then adjust to the size you want.

Comment: Using height and width will actually cause more issues if the content of the div exceeds those. Using `100%` instead of an arbitrary number of pixels would've been better, but still a poor solution.

Comment: But the content shouldn't ever exceed the width/height of a div the coder sets manually. Plus, my answer gives the coder a chance to explore the how setting the width/height actually changes their page. 

Are you saying that min-height/width is a better solution? I'm trying to figure out how my answer is in any substantive way different from yours.

Comment: Yes using minimums is better, furthermore, telling someone troubleshooting should be guess and check isn't educational its just annoying.

Comment: I disagree, and so does [Educational Theory](http://www.cin.ufpe.br/~icf/files/p189-rieman.pdf) but that is neither here nor there. I'll accept that my answer could have been better and move along :)

Comment: You failed to understand what I meant by that. You're not teaching him anything about troubleshooting if you're telling him to go guess and check. If you feel forced to do such then you're missing some level of understanding of what the actual issue is.

Comment: Where is the guess and check? Once he adds the code (even with the arbitrary number) he sees the solution. Then he adjusts the solution to fit his specific case. No guess and check, but actual learning vs simply applying an answer he doesn't understand.

Are you taking issue with the fact that I used the word "Try" as opposed to simply stating it would work?